# For-loop running more iterations than expected?

Tags: c#, for-loop, counter, increment

## Disclaimer

Im sorry for that question might be inapropriate on stack, and I probably miss something. There is just something that I totally do not understand.
Id be very happy if you could give more insights to whats happening there, or, if this question is inapropriate on stack to give me a hint where such debugging questions might be apropriate.

## Question

I recently created a unit test looping x iterations, calling a class to calculate averages.
Minimal reproducible example:

```
public void StaticPositiveValues()
{
    for (int b = 0 ; b < max; b+= stepSize)
    {
        progressingAverage.AddValue(4.0);
    }
}
```

To my understanding, `progressingAverage.AddValue(result);` is beeing called `int.MaxValue/20` (20) times.

`progressingAverage.AddValue(result);` contains a counter iterating by one each time.
Once int.max is reached in the counter, an exception is thrown.
For some unknown reason to me, this exception is beeing hit. Eventhough the amount of times it should end up at most `~20` to my understanding.

```
public class Progressing_Average_Double
{
    // init class with 0
    public Progressing_Average_Double()
    {
        _Count = 0;
        Value = 0;
    }
    // the currently calculated average
    public double Value { get; private set; }
    // the amount of values added already. Serves calculation
    private int _Count { get; set; }
    // adds a new input value to average value. 
    public void AddValue(double input)
    {
        //  at this point this class is not suitable to calculate
        if (_Count == int.MaxValue)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("max amount has been reached! use preciseaverage or moving avg instead!");
        }
        // Increments counter by one.
        _Count++;
        // calculate the new average
        Value += (input - Value) / _Count;
    }
}
```

I could imagine that in my main loop, `Progressing_Average_Double progressingAverage = new Progressing_Average_Double();` does not properly reset the class but thats mostly a shot into thin air from my part.

Comment: You step 1/20th of the full range each time, so wouldn't you expect it to only be called ~20 * ~20 times?

Comment: `int.MaxValue` is not evenly divisible by 20, so it iterates one too many times causing overflow.

Comment: yes correct. my mistake. yet hot do i get from 20 to int.max in the coutner

Comment: "To my understanding, progressingAverage.AddValue(result); is beeing called int.MaxValue/20 (20) times." - no, it's being called the *square* of that many times, because you're calling it in the inner loop body. Why do you have the inner loop (with `b`) at all if you only want to call it `int.MaxValue/20` times? Fundamentally it's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: @julianbechtold By picking a step size > `Math.Sqrt(int.MaxValue)` :)

Comment: @JonSkeet yes BUT within the outer loop, it is beeing re-initialized with new... which should reset the counter no?

Comment: Think carefully about your loop stop condition. What value can `b` take that causes the loop to terminate? Hint: there's only one possible value and, as others have said, you're not guaranteed by current logic to reach exactly that value.

Comment: the outer loop serves as a modificator to the value which is put into the average calulation. random.nextdouble only yields a result between 0..1

the inner loop serves to add the value many times in a row to see if the average(value) would drift away over time

Comment: @julianbechtold: Ah, yes. It would be useful if you would clarify that in the question. Indeed, you could make the repro much simpler by removing the outer loop entirely. That would make it more obvious that the nested loops aren't relevant - instead Damien's point explains what's going on. (I'd also *strongly* advise you to start following .NET naming conventions. It'll make the code simpler to read.)

Comment: Use uint instead of int., _for (int b = 0 ; b < max; b+= stepSize)_ b will overflow and becomes negative

Comment: @Steve what happens with uint when you overflow?

Comment: int.MaxValue = 2147483647, uint.MaxValue = 
4294967295

Comment: @julianbechtold: I strongly encourage you to research this sort of thing yourself. The answer can be found in the language specification, or via a quick search for "c# uint overflow", or you can experiment by writing a program to see what happens.

Comment: "the outer loop serves as a modificator to the value which is put into the average calulation" - is that relevant to the question you're asking though? Assuming your question is really about why the inner loop executes more often than you expect it to, the averaging aspect is irrelevant. It's always worth trying to reduce the question to a *minimal* example which demonstrates the problem.